# How can I add the objects in multiple arrays along their index

Tags: javascript

I have an array of objects

```
[
  [{data:1},{data:2},{data:3}],
  [{data:1},{data:2},{data:3}],
  [{data:1},{data:2},{data:3}]
]
```

That I need to reduce to `[{data:3},{data:6},{data:9}]` via addition.
Objects of index 0 are added, objects of index 1 are added, and objects of index 2 are added.

Is there a Javascript function like reduce that can manage this?

Comment: As far as I know, there is no native function for that, but you can always combine array functions to achieve that. Is your structure always like that? Or do you have scenarios that the arrays may have a different size?

Comment: The structure is often very similar if not identical. array sizes and object quantities are variable. @BrunoMonteiro

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I posted another alternative with a more generic code that handles your different scenarios.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The previous answer is good but it only works if your arrays are always the same size.

For example, having this initial input would break the code:

```
[
  [{data:1},{data:2},{data:3}, {data:4}],
  [{data:1},{data:2},{data:3}],
  [{data:1},{data:2},{data:3}]
]
```

*To fix that you could add a check inside the reducer, to make sure the next array has an object at that index.*

---

Another problem is if you have this initial input:

```
[
  [{data:1},{data:2},{data:3}, {data:4}],
  [{data:1},{data:2},{data:3}, {data:4}, {data:5}],
  [{data:1},{data:2},{data:3}]
]
```

The last object in the second array would be ignored because the initial reducer only takes into consideration the `length` of the first array.

---

To handle those exceptions, you could use this refactored code (based on @mickl answer):

```js
// Initial input with different format
const initialInput = [
  [{data:1},{data:2},{data:3}, {data:4}],
  [{data:1},{data:2},{data:3}, {data:4}, {data:5}],
  [{data:1},{data:2},{data:3}]
];

// Sort and reverse to get the array with most items first
const sortedInput = initialInput.sort().reverse();

// Finally use the refactored reducer
const result = sortedInput.reduce((arr,cur) => {
  return arr.map((val, i) => {
    // This "if" checks if the next array has an item on the same index of previous array
    // Which is not the case, for example, from the second to the third item
    if (cur[i] && cur[i].data) {
      return { data: val.data + cur[i].data }
    } else {
      return { data: val.data}
    }
  })
});

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`array.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencje/Obiekty/Array/Reduce) to aggregate the data across multiple arrays and `array.map` to sum up the values since it takes an arrow function where second parameter represents an index of currently processed element:

```js
let input = [
  [{data:1},{data:2},{data:3}],
  [{data:1},{data:2},{data:3}],
  [{data:1},{data:2},{data:3}]
];

let result = input.reduce((arr,cur) => 
                           arr.map((val, i) => ({ data: val.data + cur[i].data })));

console.log(result);
```